# Securing GeoServer REST and fetching ReactJS

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, authentication, react

I am in need of protecting REST API with some kind of password and then creating fetch for layers(remove,update,add, get) layers cannot really find detailed documentation with examples.

What is the best practice to fetch layers and protect REST endpoint?

I am using OpenLayers to display layers. React and Node.js

Comment: I don't think GeoServer REST API is intended to fetch data, just for system administration, which is why you not finding any examples

Comment: @nmtoken what do you recommend then to protect routes cause now they are open to everyone getCapabilites one for example and I would still like to be able to add new layers and be able to edit data of layers :)

Comment: the rest API is already password protected - you should use WFS or WFS-T to fetch and change data

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

As `NmToken` says in the comments you don't want to use the REST API which is used for automating the administration of GeoServer. To fetch data you want to use the [WMS (for images of your map)](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/index.html) or [WFS (for the vector data)](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/index.html).

As for securing your service, you need to consult the [user manual's security section](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/index.html#security)